# Where to put preseed.cfg on flash drive install?

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation, preseed

I am trying to boot a machine to the Ubuntu Server installer without a local monitor or keyboard.  Therefore I want it to start the installation with a preseed that setups up SSH with a user and pass.

I know how to configure the preseed, but I don't know where to put it.  I copied the Ubuntu Server ISO to my flash drive, and I see:

```
preseed/cli.seed
preseed/cloud.seed
preseed/ubuntu-server.seed
preseed/ubuntu-server-minimal.seed
preseed/ubuntu-server-minimalvm.seed
```

Are any of these run by default, or are these examples?

I also have:

```
boot/
boot/grub
```

Do I place something called `preseed.cfg` in one of those directories?

I don't want to have to type anything at a command prompt after the system boots to select the preseed, as I want to do it without local keyboard/monitor.

Answer (score 0):

From the debian help on this I would put it in the `root` of your install (1st line of this:)

> **[B.2.1. Loading the preconfiguration file](https://www.debian.org/releases/etch/hppa/apbs02.html.en)**
>
> If you are using initrd preseeding, you only have to make sure a file named `preseed.cfg` is included in the root directory of the initrd. The installer will automatically check if this file is present and load it.
>
> For the other preseeding methods you need to tell the installer what file to use when you boot it. This is normally done by passing the kernel a boot parameter, either manually at boot time or by editing the bootloader configuration file (e.g. `syslinux.cfg`) and adding the parameter to the end of the append line(s) for the kernel.
>
> If you do specify the preconfiguration file in the bootloader configuration, you might change the configuration so you don't need to hit enter to boot the installer. For syslinux this means setting the timeout to 1 in `syslinux.cfg`.
>
> To make sure the installer gets the right preconfiguration file, you can optionally specify a checksum for the file. Currently this needs to be a md5sum, and if specified it must match the preconfiguration file or the installer will refuse to use it.